# $\neg(\forall x,p(x))\iff\exists x,\neg p(x)$ is a rule?

Tags: logic

The statement, $\neg(\forall x,p(x))\iff\exists x,\neg p(x)$ is pretty clear to me and I was wondering if it is a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some books this is a theorem, and in some books this is indeed the definition of $\forall$. That is,  assuming the law of the excluded middle, $\forall x$ is nothing more than a faster, and often more readable way to write the symbol combination $$\lnot \exists x \lnot$$